# Javascript's Callback Function

Tags: javascript

I am using Lazy Load Jquery plugin here on my test page: http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/03/testing-2_04.html
And this is the minified script for lazyload:
Code:

```
<script src="http://files.cryoffalcon.com/javascript/jquery.lazyload.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

this one is to trigger lazy load:
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(function() {
          $("img").lazyload({
     effect : "fadeIn"
 });
      });
  </script>
```

In the above script I have added fadeIn effect to it, I don't know if I have done it right according to script writting I am not good in scripts ^^ So, I would like have an advise if it's well written or there is some comma mistake.

But that is not my important question, all of the above lazy load plugin is used with QuickSand Jquery plugin that I am using for sorting.
QuickSand Jquery Plugin requires callback function if it's tooltip or Lazy Load, So can someone kindly tell me how to make lazy load work together with quicksand jquery.
Here is the quicksand's script:

Code:

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
(function(cash) {
 $.fn.sorted = function(customOptions) {
  var options = {
   reversed: false,
   by: function(a) {
    return a.text();
   }
  };
  $.extend(options, customOptions);

  $data = $(this);
  arr = $data.get();
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {

      var valA = options.by($(a));
      var valB = options.by($(b));
   if (options.reversed) {
    return (valA &lt; valB) ? 1 : (valA &gt; valB) ? -1 : 0;    
   } else {  
    return (valA &lt; valB) ? -1 : (valA &gt; valB) ? 1 : 0; 
   }
  });
  return $(arr);
 };

})(jQuery);

$(function() {

  var read_button = function(class_names) {
    var r = {
      selected: false,
      type: 0
    };
    for (var i=0; i &lt; class_names.length; i++) {
      if (class_names[i].indexOf('selected-') == 0) {
        r.selected = true;
      }
      if (class_names[i].indexOf('segment-') == 0) {
        r.segment = class_names[i].split('-')[1];
      }
    };
    return r;
  };

  var determine_sort = function($buttons) {
    var $selected = $buttons.parent().filter('[class*=&quot;selected-&quot;]');
    return $selected.find('a').attr('data-value');
  };

  var determine_kind = function($buttons) {
    var $selected = $buttons.parent().filter('[class*=&quot;selected-&quot;]');
    return $selected.find('a').attr('data-value');
  };

  var $preferences = {
    duration: 800,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
    adjustHeight: 'dynamic'
  };

  var $list = $('#data');
  var $data = $list.clone();

  var $controls = $('ul#gamecategories ul');

  $controls.each(function(i) {

    var $control = $(this);
    var $buttons = $control.find('a');

    $buttons.bind('click', function(e) {

      var $button = $(this);
      var $button_container = $button.parent();
      var button_properties = read_button($button_container.attr('class').split(' '));      
      var selected = button_properties.selected;
      var button_segment = button_properties.segment;

      if (!selected) {

        $buttons.parent().removeClass('selected-0').removeClass('selected-1').removeClass('selected-2');
        $button_container.addClass('selected-' + button_segment);

        var sorting_type = determine_sort($controls.eq(1).find('a'));
        var sorting_kind = determine_kind($controls.eq(0).find('a'));

        if (sorting_kind == 'all') {
          var $filtered_data = $data.find('li');
        } else {
          var $filtered_data = $data.find('li.' + sorting_kind);
        }

        if (sorting_type == 'size') {
          var $sorted_data = $filtered_data.sorted({
            by: function(v) {
              return parseFloat($(v).find('span').text());
            }
          });
        } else {
          var $sorted_data = $filtered_data.sorted({
            by: function(v) {
              return $(v).find('strong').text().toLowerCase();
            }
          });
        }

        $list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences, function () { $(this).tooltip (); } );

      }

      e.preventDefault();
    });

  }); 

var high_performance = true;  
  var $performance_container = $('#performance-toggle');
  var $original_html = $performance_container.html();

  $performance_container.find('a').live('click', function(e) {
    if (high_performance) {
      $preferences.useScaling = false;
      $performance_container.html('CSS3 scaling turned off. Try the demo again. &lt;a href=&quot;#toggle&quot;&gt;Reverse&lt;/a&gt;.');
      high_performance = false;
    } else {
      $preferences.useScaling = true;
      $performance_container.html($original_html);
      high_performance = true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
&lt;/script&gt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
$list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences, function(){
    $(this).tooltip ();
    $("img").lazyload({
        effect : "fadeIn"
    });
});
```

Comment: then you should wait for smarter programmer than me as I am a beginner, don't worry this place is filled with geniuses, very soon you will have your issue solved and it is not big either. It's just me who is new to this.